C# EF Core connection open interceptor
I am using ASP.NET Core and ADO.NET commands for SQL operations. I am looking for a way to intercept the SQL connection.Open() and then insert the UserID into the session_context prior to the SqlCommand being executed.
This is the SQL command:
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();

    string sql = "UPDATE Customer SET CompanyName = @CompanyName, EmailAddress = @EmailAddress WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID";

    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Clear();
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", customer.CompanyName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", customer.EmailAddress);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", customer.CustomerID);

        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

Then I tried to write an extension to intercept the ConnectionOpening, but this was never called.
public class DbLogUserIdInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
{
    public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(
            DbConnection connection,
            ConnectionEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult result)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Connection is opening... insert UserID into session_context");
        return base.ConnectionOpening(connection, eventData, result);
    }
}

This is my DbContext where it added a call to AddInterceptors:
public class Database1DbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public Database1DbContext(DbContextOptions<Database1DbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AWCustomer> Customer { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.AddInterceptors(new DbLogUserIdInterceptor());
    }
}

Please advise.

I don't see how entity framework is related. There's no context involved in the connection you want to observe.

I am new to Entity Framework, so now I just learned that conn.Open() is not EF.  Do you have any suggestion similar to interceptor for EF, but it executes globally when a connection.Open() directly instead?

No, there's nothing that notifies opening of connections. But if you're going to use EF, you don't want to use SqlCommands anyway to do updates. You want EF to do that. Once you have that running you can set values like UserID in a SaveChanges override of the context. It doesn't require anything fancy.

The app is mixed with EF and ADO.NET.  For any SQL operations with EF, I can use "DbCommandInterceptor".  For ADO.NET SQL operations (e.g. Conn.Open() SQLCommand...), I am looking a way to intercept like EF but for ADO.NET.  Please see my response below regarding to your question "globally".

You wont see the ConnectionOppening method of your interceptor being called automatically because you are using ADO.NET directly instead of going through Entity Framework. The interceptor is designed to work with EF Core's Database operations, so when you create and open a SqlConnection directly, it bypasses EF Core's interception pipeline.
you can manually do it like this:
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    // Manually insert the UserID into session context
    var interceptor = new DbLogUserIdInterceptor();
    interceptor.InsertUserIdIntoSessionContext(connection, GetCurrentUserId());

    connection.Open();
    // Then proceed with your SQL command...
}


I was looking for a way so that I don't have to modified all existing SQLConnection operations, but i guess that works too.  Thank you!

How is this going to do anything globally when a connection opens?

The thinking is that when the Connection.Open(), there is a globally/base class for conn.Open() like DbConnectionInterceptor, it will set the SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("EXEC sp_set_session_context 'UserID', '123'", conn), then execute it to store the userID in session_context.  That way any SQLCommand execute right after, it will track changes by the SQL trigger.  I know I can create a separate function to perform the above set session_context and call that function every time conn.open() but hoping for better way where I can implement one place globally (like interceptor) instead.
